# Singleton SqlSession not suitable for multi-user batch processing?

Tags: spring, mybatis

I have created a supper DAO Class which DAO classes extend for batch processing and it worked nicely for one user as expected.

But I am concerned that this might cause serious problems like deadlock or unwanted sql flush when over 2 users use SqlSession(batchSqlssion) concurrently.

I wonder if I have to produce SqlSession for each user? I mean a prototype bean.

```
@Component
public class BatchDaoSupport {

    private SqlSession batchSqlSession;

    @Resource(name="batchSqlSession")
    SqlSessionFactory sf;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initBatchSqlSession(){
        this.batchSqlSession = new SqlSessionTemplate(sf);
    }

public int batchInsert(String queryId, Object parameterObject) {
    return getBatchSqlSession().insert(queryId, parameterObject);
}

public SqlSession getBatchSqlSession() {
    return this.batchSqlSession;
}

public void flush(){
    getBatchSqlSession().flushStatements();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation :

***SqlSessionTemplate*** = Thread safe, Spring managed, SqlSession that works with Spring transaction management to ensure that that the actual SqlSession used is the one associated with the current Spring transaction. In addition, it manages the session life-cycle, including closing, committing or rolling back the session as necessary based on the Spring transaction configuration.

http://mybatis.org/spring/apidocs/reference/org/mybatis/spring/SqlSessionTemplate.html

Basically, the transaction manager will take responsibility so your queries never conflict. The answer is **no**, you don't need to create two of them.